# Equivalent of CREATE2 address generation in JS

Tags: solidity, evm, keccak

I have this solidity code from PancakeSwap's library, want to generate the same result in JS using ethers or Web3. How can I achieve that ?

```
 address(uint(keccak256(abi.encodePacked(
            hex'ff',
            factory, //is Address
            keccak256(abi.encodePacked(token0, token1)), //token0 and token1 are addresses
            hex'00fb7f630766e6a796048ea87d01acd3068e8ff67d078148a3fa3f4a84f69bd5' // init code hash
        ))));
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me know if you're strictly limited with Ethers and Web3. If it's possible to lift this one, then you could use this module: https://github.com/emilbayes/eth-create2.

Answer (score 0):

There are two handy resources that do the same as you requested. They both use Solidity via ethersJS to the work done.

1. This one hand holds through the process steps
   https://docs.alchemy.com/docs/create2-an-alternative-to-deriving-contract-addresses
2. https://github.com/thegostep/solidity-create2-deployer